# Getting a column in an NSTableView with editable column order

Tags: macos, cocoa, cell, nstableview, nstablecolumn

I have an `NSTableView` where I would like to be notified if the user clicks in a column "ClickMe". I linked the entire table view to a method which can extract the `clickedColumn:`, but I get an absolute number and not a reference to the "ClickMe" column (which may have been moved to another place).

I could of course program my own search algorithm to see if column X is actually the "Clickme" column, but that would not be very elegant. Is there a way to identify columns properly, and to receive that ID programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do my own search in a fairly fast way, but I still have a feeling I am putting too much effort in this:

First, set the Identifier of the desired column in the Interface Builder to "ClickMeColumn". Then:

```
NSInteger cmColumn = [tableView columnWithIdentifier:@"ClickMeColumn"];
if ( [tableView clickedColumn] == cmColumn )
      NSLog(@"Clicked me!");
```

I am looking for something along the lines of `[tableView clickedColumnIdentifier]`.

Answer (score 0):

What about querying NSTableView's columnAtPoint: in your table views mouseDown: or mouseUp: method?

Comment: No, I do not want an index, I want a UID. Because column #6 is may or may not be the right one, depending on where my "ClickMe" column is. Example: if you want to get access to a column with a person's last name, but the user moved that column from the first position to the last in the table, index 1 will not get me the last name anymore, right?

Comment: What is the tableviews Mouse up/ mouse down method?

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the methods below. Called by the tableView's delegate on selection. You can extract the identifier and the title string from the relevant tableColumn.

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didClickTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn {

NSLog(@"tableView:didClickTableColumn: %@, titleString: %@", [tableColumn identifier], [[tableColumn headerCell] stringValue]);

}


- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn {

NSLog(@"tableView:mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn: %@, titleString: %@", [tableColumn identifier], [[tableColumn headerCell] stringValue]);

}
```

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class